# How did Omar and Butch originally meet?

Tags: the-wire

I am almost finished with season 4 of the wire - on the season finale - I am wanting to know how Omar and Butch originally met or how they know each other.  They have a unique bond and Omar can always count on him when he does not have many he can indeed count on.  Thank you for your help on this.

Comment: Very good question!  And I wish I knew.  Watching it through for the second time and I'm almost done.

Comment: I've watched through a few times. I don't believe anything definitive is ever mentioned. I just assume he knows Omar from Omar growing up, or certainly as he grew up in the Game.